# What does it mean to say a quotient of fractional ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraic number field, and $R$ its ring of integers. If $I$ and $J$ are two fractional ideal in $\mathbb{K}$ such that $J \subseteq I$, what does it mean to say $I/J$? What is the difference from integral ideals?

Comment: Maybe it is meant $\;I\cdot J^{-1}\;$ ? Do you know in some cases the set of all fractional ideals (done with an integer domain, field of fractions and etc.) is a group?

Comment: Yes I know that, but is this equivalent to say $I$ modulo $J$?

Comment: $I/J$ is a torsion module over dedekind ring $O_K$. It is not even an integral ideal. Note that $J$ contains a $Q$ basis of $K$. All integral ideals are torsion free as submodule of $O_K$. The text might mean $IJ^{-1}$ which is another fractional ideal. Once you multiply $IJ^{-1}$ by an appropriate factor of $K$, it will become integral ideal.